# Storing a JSON file in a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, json

May i know how to store a JSON file in a javascript variable, I am trying below but not working

```
 var json = JSON.parse(readJSON('test.json'));
 alert(json);
```

Comment: Are you attempting to read json from a local file? Unless we don't see readJSON method, we will not be able to help you.

Comment: What does readJSON do, does it work?

Comment: alert the json variable using stringify. Then u can see the result JSON. alert(JSON.stringify(json))

Comment: "not working" is a very poor description of the problem. What happens when you use that? What do you expect to happen? What error messages are reported?

Comment: What is `readJSON`? You need to provide a [mcve]. A fragment of your code is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

require should do the trick.

```
var json = require('test.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using Node.js, but in that case you need to create a function that read your json file `fs.readFileSync` or `fs.readFile` from the library file system `const fs = require('fs');` then use `JSON.parse` to parse the string and convert the string to object.

If you are not using Node.js you can use an ajax call to load your json file and then parse it to an object.

Good luck!